# Low volume from rear line out, fine from the front panel

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

When I plug my headphones in the jack on the rear panel of my machine, the sound comes out low, **even after I turn up every imaginable slider** from PulseAudio or AlsaMixer or whatever. When I plug them in the front panel, everything is great. I don't do that, though, because there is some noise and buzzing whenever audio isn't playing, and I think that it's a hardware problem I'm not interested in dealing with (since, after all, there's the rear ports).

On my Windows partition I *am* able to configure the rear port for headphone use correctly via the interface provided by Realtek.

Fedora doesn't seem to give me such an option, though. What should I do?

EDIT - I'm including the output of `amixer -D hw:0 contents`: http://pastebin.com/09KPX89E

Comment: It sounds like you've found a bug in the Linux driver for your sound hardware. At least if you've checked the controls (non-slider) as well. I guess please [edit] in the output of `amixer -D hw:0 contents` (use whichever -D option is needed, need to get the ALSA mixer not the PulseAudio mixer).

Comment: Done, I think it's the right mixer.